# Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

When I create a new blank cross-platform project in Visual Studio 2017 I get about six errors. All on 'MainActivity.cs' page. I'm running VS2017 that updated to support Core 2.1. I'm not sure what I need to install or change to fix this.

I'm using

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

and under tools and extensions, everything is up to date.

```
   namespace HelloWorld.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "HelloWorld", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = 
"@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = 
ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
      public class MainActivity : 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
}
```

errors(I get these errors every time I create a blank project)

> Error CS0103  The name 'LoadApplication' does not exist in the current context
> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace
> Error CS0115  'MainActivity.OnCreate(Bundle)': no suitable method found to override
> Error CS0103  The name 'ToolbarResource' does not exist in the current context
> Error CS0103  The name 'TabLayoutResource' does not exist in the current context
> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms'

I'm new to Xamarin and I tried to add references to my project but I'm not sure which of the 3 projects to add references or what references I need.

Comment: Did you update all the Nugets to their respective latest versions?

Comment: Yes, everything is updated. I'm thinking I got something updated that's not capable

Comment: What xf version are you using?

Comment: I got it to work, what I did was went to help in VS2017 and updated to 15.9.6 and it recommended an update to Android SDK. So I updated it all and cleaned and rebuild project and that fixed the issue. When I first ran the project it told me some Android references need updating and I updated from the error list and in nuget panel. I guess sometimes you have to update from the help menu as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, doing the below solved the issue:

what I did was went to help in `VS2017` and updated to `15.9.6` and it recommended an update to `Android SDK`. So I updated it all and cleaned and rebuild project and that fixed the issue. When I first ran the project it told me some `Android references need updating` and I updated from the error list and in the `NuGet`panel. And it worked

Answer (score 0):

When using Xamarin.Forms Version 5.0.0.x change
MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity to MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity. That solved the error.